# Backbone.js Still Setting Model Attributes on Validation Failure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some strange reason my model is still setting attributes when I return a string in the models validation. Here is my code validation code:

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function( attributes ){
        var tax = attributes.tax;

        if(tax.amount < 0.0 || typeof tax.amount !== "number"){
            return "The tax amount cannot be negative and must be a number.";
        }
    },
   defaults: {
       "tax": {
            "amount": 100
       }
   },
   setTax: function(amount){
      var tax = this.get("tax");
      tax.amount = amount;
      this.set("tax", tax);
   }
})
```

I then have the model listen for the error event and console log it through:

```
    model = new Model();

    View = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.model.on('error', function(model, error){
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
            })
        }
    });
    view = new View({model: model});
    view.model.setTax(-100);
```

The console log is being printed, but for some reason the model is still setting the property. Is there anything I need to return to not have the model set the property? According to the Backbone.js docks if you return anything from the validation then it is suppose to not set the property. I'm using Backbone.js version 0.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
var tax = this.get("tax");
```

The `get` method basically does `return this.attributes[attr]` and the `tax` attribute is an object, the result is that your `var tax` and the model's `this.attributes.tax` are the same thing. So, when you say `tax.amount = amount`, you're actually directly editing the `tax` that is inside the model's `attributes`.

When working with mutable attributes (i.e. anything other than numbers, strings, and booleans), you need to make copies before changing them:

```
setTax: function(amount) {
    var tax = _(this.get("tax")).clone();
    tax.amount = amount;
    this.set("tax", tax);
}
```

Making a copy also prevents Backbone from thinking that your `set` call isn't actually doing anything. If you don't clone the `tax` as above, you won't trigger the change event on the model and that's probably not what you want.

A few examples (open your console please):

- [Invalid tax amount with a `_.clone` in `setTax`.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nQAcC/)
- [Valid tax amount with a `_.clone` and a change handler.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kMuj8/)
- [Valid tax amount without `_.clone` and with a change handler.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Xcbqe/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, my actual model is much more complex then the one that I gave; I shortened it down for the example. I tried the clone, but I'm still running into the same problem. Clone appears to only creates copies of the first level of properties of the model that you are cloning. I forked your fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/NeHkm/. I assume the only way around this is to clone every property of the object?

Comment: Yeah, according to the Underscore.js docs it appears that the clone function simply: Create a shallow-copied clone of the object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

Comment: @PhillipWhisenhunt: Yes, `_.clone` only does a shallow copy, you can use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to do a deep copy. However, if your attributes are that complicated, you might want to rethink your data structure.